# FULLTEXT SEARCH not working mysql

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

So i get an error when i try and use

```
SELECT views, keywords, title, url, thumbnail, 
       MATCH(keywords,title) AGAINST ('%$search_value%') AS relevance 
  FROM straight 
 WHERE MATCH (keywords,title) AGAINST ('%$search_value%') 
 ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

This is due to me not having FULLtext search enabled, but i cant seem to enable it. when i run the sql below:

```
ALTER TABLE straight ADD FULLTEXT(keywords, title)
```

i get this response:

```
MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 3.8022 sec)
```

Then when trying to run the first query again i get the failed

```
#1191 - Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list
```

I can't tell why it's not registering. Any help would be great.
Thanks!

Edit:

My tabel:

```
CREATE TABLE `straight` (
  `url` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `keywords` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `production` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `categories` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `views` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `likes` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `length` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `thumbnail` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `url` (`url`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `url_2` (`url`,`title`,`keywords`,`production`,
         `categories`,`views`,`likes`,`length`,`thumbnail`,`date`
), ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running? Can you please edit your question to display the definition of your `straight` table? In some versions, your table has to be in the `MyISAM` access method. Also, you don't need the `%` signs in your `AGAINST()` parameter in `FULLTEXT`.

Comment: @OllieJones The table is the MyISAM storage engine. I am unsure how to check version of MySQL this is on a hostgator sever. Thanks

Comment: Server version doesn't matter if table is MyISAM.

Comment: @OllieJones what else could it be? Any ideas?

Comment: Please post your table definition, after you create the index.

Comment: @OllieJones how do i do this sorry im not sure i know what you mrsn

Answer (score 0):

You need a FULLTEXT index that matches, exactly, the columns upon which you want to search. The FULLTEXT index you have has more columns than you need.

Try adding the one you mentioned.

```
ALTER TABLE straight ADD FULLTEXT(keywords, title)
```

Then look at the table definition and make sure it's there.